# JDesktopPane não remove renderização de tela fechada, como proceder?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

Criei uma tela básica com NetBeans que possui um menu e um `JDesktopPane` que abre os `JInternalFrame` referenciados pelo menu:

[image: screenshot da tela sem o bug]

Assim como uma função para abrir esses `JInternalFrame`:

```
private void openView(JInternalFrame view){
    // o "frameInterno" referencia o JDesktopPane
    this.frameInterno.removeAll();
    this.frameInterno.add(view);
    view.setVisible(true);
}

private void itemClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    this.openView(new ClienteView());
}
```

Porém, se tento abrir outra tela com a mesma função, a tela continua com a imagem da renderização anterior gravada ao fundo:

[image: tela do sistema com o bug]

Estou utilizando o Look and Feel [`JTattoo`](http://www.jtattoo.net/), mas mesmo usando o Nimbus ou o default o problema persiste.

O que pode estar causando essa falha? Como posso resolver?

**Configurações do sistema**:

Kubuntu 18.04 LTS
OpenJDK 1.8

[Repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/arthursiq5/jLanches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão que eu acho que está em jogo aqui é que você não está chamando um método para redesenhar o Panel. Isto é bem comum, enquanto trabalhando com GUIs em Java. Existem métodos para cada GUI que resolvem esse problema, por exemplo:

em swing temos essa thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347076/how-to-remove-all-components-from-a-jframe-in-java

Só nessa thread, a comunidade já fez de várias formas diferentes.

```
private void openView(JInternalFrame view){
    // o "frameInterno" referencia o JDesktopPane
    this.frameInterno.removeAll();
    //Tente algo nessas linhas para começo de conversa
    this.PanelPrincipal.repaint();
    revalidate();
    validate(); 
    this.revalidate();
    this.validate()
    //Além disso, sugiro inverter a ordem abaixo: primeiro deixar visivel e depois adicionar ao Frame.
    this.frameInterno.add(view);
    view.setVisible(true);
}
```

Algumas dicas extra para ajudar a nivel de código (work-arounds):

1. Você pode criar uma rotina, que percorre dentro de um for Frame por Frame (exceto o Principal) e executa o conteúdo da action X desses Frames.
2. Caso você tenha percebido que a rotina que você postou aqui só passa a funcionar para mais de 2 Frames abertos, então pode ser algo relacionado à falta de uma palavra-reservada que dê um "refresh" nos frames.
3. Você pode criar um método Gerenciador, que fica verificando Eventos (mais ou menos o que eu descrevi em 1) de dentro da função principal de forma síncrona ou tu podes implementar threads que verifiquem isso de tempos em tempos com um auxílio de mutex ou semáforo.

Com a limitação que tenho do tópico, sem conhecer o seu projeto, é isso que posso lhe oferecer. Boa sorte!